# Sort / get max member and id out of a nested-list in Prolog?

Tags: sorting, prolog, max, nested-lists, swi-prolog

Let's consider I have some findall like this:

```
findall([ID, Val], (some_predicate(ID, Val), Val >= 50), XS).
```

This ends up in a list of lists (or tuples?!) like:

```
[[2, 51], [3, 102], [8, 287], [11, 157]]
```

How can I sort this list by value (descending)?

At the end I would like to get the following:

```
[Max|RS] = SortedByValue.
Max = [8, 287],
RS = [[11, 157], [3, 102], [2, 51]].
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sort by value, do you have to order your pairs with the `Id` first? It's easier if you don't. `setof/3` will order your pairs in ascending order by their first component, then you can reverse them:

```
max_rest(MaxPair, RS) :-
    setof([Val, Id], (some_predicate(Id, Val), Val >= 50), XS),
    reverse(XS, [MaxPair | RS]).
```

If you really need the results with the `Id` first, you can remap them:

```
swap([A, B], [B, A]).

max_rest(MaxPair, RS) :-
    setof([Val, Id], (some_predicate(Id, Val), Val >= 50), XValIds),
    maplist(swap, XValIds, XIdVals),
    reverse(XIdVals, [MaxPair | RS]).
```

Comment: No, I do not need this exact order, it is just the natural order in my database. However, remapping to get the original order is a nice add-on! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you create a predicate that trasform your list of list of two elements in a list of pairs (observe: a predicate that works in both directions) inverting the order of the pairs

```
listPairConverter([], []).

listPairConverter([[K, V] | Ti], [V-K | To]) :-
  listPairConverter(Ti, To).
```

and a predicate that reverse a list

```
reverseList([], Rl, Rl).

reverseList([H | T], Rl, Acc) :-
  reverseList(T, Rl, [H | Acc]).
```

using the iso predicate `keysort/2`, you can write a predicate that sort the list according the second element of the internal list as follows

```
sortValue(Li, Lo) :-
  listPairConverter(Li, R0),
  keysort(R0, R1),
  listPairConverter(R2, R1),
  reverseList(R2, Lo, []).
```

So calling

```
sortValue([[2, 51], [3, 102], [8, 287], [11, 157]], Lo)
```

you can unify `Lo` with

```
[[8,287],[11,157],[3,102],[2,51]]
```

Comment: You can use `maplist/3` to implement your list-pair converter in a nice way. Define `list_pair([A,B], A-B).` then use `maplist(list_pair, Lists, Pairs).`

Comment: @lurker: why not library(yall) ? `maplist([[A,B],A-B]>>true,Lists,Pairs).`

Comment: @CapelliC that's even better. I wasn't thinking about `library(yall)`, so great comment.

Answer (score 1):

your problem fits exactly in library([solution_sequences](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=solutionsequences)):

```
?- findall([ID, Val], order_by([desc(Val)], (some_predicate(ID, Val), Val >= 50)), [Max|Rs]).
Max = [8, 287],
Rs = [[11, 157], [3, 102], [2, 51]].
```

The library is pretty new, since I never used it before, I got that result with the following test steps:

```
?- [library(solution_sequences)].
true.

?- [user].
some_predicate(ID,Val) :- member([ID,Val],[[2, 51], [3, 102], [8, 287], [11, 157]]).
|: (^D here)true.

?- order_by([desc(Val)], (some_predicate(ID, Val), Val >= 50)).
Val = 287,
ID = 8 ;
Val = 157,
ID = 11 ;
...
```